# Prevent resending of form data (POST) and POST sending from bots

Tags: php, forms, security, post, bots

I know there are plenty of answers of how to prevent the resending of the data when using the refresh button. But what do I do if I want to make sure that the data isn´t from a bot, too ?

Well of course I can´t make sure that it isn´t sent from a bot, but what I mean is the manipulating of the numbers.

I have a small script where you can vote for A or B, every time you vote A and B is something different, but if you captcha the post data, you can resend this time over time. Is there a way to solve this without saving the data from the previeus two options into the database or to a file ? Should I use a session for this, which I think isn´t safe, too ? 
I would have to save the IP with the previeus options on the server, I think. Or set a uniquie token for 5 seconds, like a secret key, which is sent with post and only allowed once.

I hope you understood what I mean, I tried my best to write it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using a CAPTCHA mechanism. To avoid the reuse of a CAPTCHA token, you should **invalidate** the token right after its verification even if the token is invalid.

```
$token = $_SESSION['captcha_token'];
unset($_SESSION['captcha_token']); //Avoid reuse

if($_POST['token'] === $token) {
    //Do something
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the captcha token expire after you receive it the first time.